# File Name capturing form path

Tags: regex

I could have sworn i have done this before, but.... no go.

I am trying to copy the file name from each line of the sample data below to the beginning of the line. However, when when i add parathensis to the expression to capture the file name it is deleted. I have tried several variations.

**Regex Expresion**

```
[^\\/:*?<>]+$
```

The expression successfully captures the file names on each line.

**Sample Data**

```
c:\Dir1\dir2\Samplefile.txt
c:\Dir1\dir2\dir3\Sample file.txt
c:\Dir1\dir2\Samplefile
c:\Dir1\dir2\dir3\Sample file
c:\Dir1\wp_movfiles_20160911024934.ini
c:\Dir1\\dir2\wp_movfiles_20160911055222.ini
```

**desire results**

```
Samplefile.txt    c:\Dir1\dir2\Samplefile.txt
Sample file.txt   c:\Dir1\dir2\dir3\Sample file.txt
Samplefile        c:\Dir1\dir2\Samplefile
Sample file       c:\Dir1\dir2\dir3\Sample file
wp_movfiles_20160911024934.ini       c:\Dir1\wp_movfiles_20160911024934.ini
wp_movfiles_20160911055222.ini       c:\Dir1\\dir2\wp_movfiles_20160911055222.ini
```

any assitance is greatly appricated. thank you.

Comment: I don't get this question. You capture all filenames correctly with your regex https://www.regex101.com/r/gymK9t/1

Comment: correct- the issues lies when capturing  the file name and the complete line with parathensis. so they can be referenced with \1 and \2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get away with using this regex:

```
.*\\(.*)$
```

This will greedily consume everything in the file path from left to right, until hitting the final backslash.  Then it will stop, and capture everything which comes after that final backslash, which should be the file name.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: You are 100% correct!  - not sure why i was complicating so much!  added the second grouping to be able to have two fields -  (.*\\(.*))$   thank you!